# Are there absolutely isolated quantum systems in the Universe?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, universe

The university began to study quantum entanglement, and the teacher said that in order to get entangled, systems must have low entropy. I did not understand this point very well, that is, systems with high entropy cannot be entangled? And the main question: in the Universe, all quantum systems are in one way or another entangled with each other, or are there systems that are absolutely isolated and not entangled with anything? Could such systems even exist in our Universe?

Comment: Your secondary question is a good one, but is different enough that I think it merits its own post. There are multiple ways that it could be interpreted, so a good answer would be a bit long to combine with an answer to your main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given known physics, it is difficult to imagine a perfectly isolated system. Even the most empty parts of the universe are filled with [neutrinos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino) and [blackbody radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation), and it is basically impossible to completely remove them from a volume of space. All known particles experience interactions (if they didn't, then how could we know of their existence?), and interactions can lead to entanglement. For example, when two particles scatter (bounce) off of each other, they can scatter off in multiple different directions, which results in entanglement between their final directions of propagation.

You might imagine that in the instant following measurement, a quantum system has collapsed into a single definitive state, which would imply the complete absence of entanglement. However this only works if you can be exactly 100% confident in the measurement outcome. As realistic measurements are imperfect, it is not possible to perfectly remove entanglement in this way. This limitation is related to the concept of [weak measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_measurement), which is usually omitted from introductory quantum mechanics courses.

Researchers in quantum computing attempt to engineer perfectly isolated quantum systems for information storage and processing, but as usual, perfection appears to be unattainable, basically for the above reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In addition, I think, since quantum particles are not separate objects, but excitations of single quantum fields, it is impossible absolutely separate them.